# ORM Django составление запросов

Tags: python, django

Вопрос о порядке составления сложных запросов к БД на джанге.
У меня есть три модели:

- основная модель объекта, который имеет отношения к другим моделям

  ```
    class Res(models.Model):
       name = models.CharField(verbose_name='Наименование', max_length=20)
       related_rich = models.ForeignKey(Rich, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)
       related_registration = models.ForeignKey(Registration, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)
  ```
- и две другие модели:

  ```
   сlass Rich(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30, verbose_name='Наименование', unique=True)


   class Registration(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30, verbose_name='Наименование', unique=True)
  ```

В проекте есть представления в виде списков по всем моделям. С первой моделью все более или менее понятно - чтобы вытащить связанные объекты мы  просто выбираем команду select_related. То при выводе списка Rich мне недостаточно просто вывести prefetch_related('Res'), необходимо также вывести объекты Registration которые имеют отношение к связанным с Rich объектам Res.
Подскажите каким образом необходимо составить корректный запрос к БД чтобы вытащить всю информацию одним запросом.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вам необходимо сделать `Prefetch`

```
from django.dЬ.models import Prefetch

Rich.objects.all().prefetch_related(
   Prefetch('res_set', queryset=Res.objects.all().select_related('related_registration'))
)
```